# Query to find only rows that meet certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a particular sync & cb, I would only need the records if all the rows are `not available`. From below I need the output for Bal and BAL1 only since all the rows are `not available`

```
sync    cb        value
 Bal    BAL1      not avaialble
 Bal    BAL1      not available
 Bal    BAL1      not available
 Bal    BAL1      not available
 order  OR1CNV0   abcdef
 order  OR1CNV0   not available
 order  OR1CNV0   not available
 order  OR1CNV0   not available
```

Answer (score 3):

One aggregation option:

```sql
SELECT sync, cb
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY sync, cb
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN value <> 'not available' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not exists` if you want the original rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.sync = t.sync and t2.cb = t.cb and
                        t2.value <> 'not available'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function if you want to display all the relevant rows without grouping:

```sql
SELECT t.sync, t.cb
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      CountNA = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.value <> 'not available' THEN 1 END)
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE t.CountNA = 0;
```